# how to break the title written inside bquote function of base R

Tags: r

I want to break the title in the code below into three lines, but it seems not working for me using `\n` at three place inside the string. Does anyone know how to do it?
below is the code

```
bquote("Product of tissueAvs.tissueB" ~ L[2]~'FC' ~ "and tissueBvs.tissueA" ~ L[2]~'FC')
```

thank you!

Comment: You can just use `"\n"` inside the string. R won't show the line break unless you print it with `cat`. So if you wrap your call to `bquote` in `cat` it will show the line breaks. I'm not sure however, why you use `bquote` it seems you are not evaluating objects with `.()` inside `bquote`. Are you sure you want to use `bquote()`?

Comment: I just want to past in my plot as title. Thank you for answering my question

Comment: I'm not sure what `L[2]` is (is this your plot?). And what are the tilde `~` operators for? (is this the location you want to insert `\n`?). I think it would be easier if you could show your code and expected result.

Comment: L stands for log-- so i want to say log2fold change

Comment: L stands for log-- so i want to say log2fold change. `bquote("Product of tissueAvs.tissueB\n" ~ L[2]~'FC' ~ "and \n tissueBvs.tissueA" ~ L[2]~'FC')`